# Как в андроид приложении создать 1 обработчик нажатия для группы кнопок созданных из кода?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть группа кнопок создающихся внутри TableLayout

```
for( int i=0; i<helth; i++)
    {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gold);

        for( int j=0; j<width; j++)
        {
            ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.question);
            imageView.setId(kid);
            mass[i][j] = kid;
            ++kid;


            tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
        }

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow, i);
    }
```

Мне нужно обрабатывать нажатия на эти кнопки, но я не представляю себе возможным работать через интерфейс View.OnClickListener(). По сути мне нужно обращаться к кнопкам по их id. Я загружаю все id в класс ресурсов, но что делать дальше, я не знаю.

Comment: В чём трудность? Где-то до выполнения этого кода создаёте экземпляр `View.OnClickListener()`, в цикле прикрепляете его всем кнопкам. В `onClick(View v)` вам передаётся именно та кнопка, которую нажали. `v.getId()` - вот вам и её `id`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я не совсем понял как вы предлагаете сделать.

Comment: View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for( int i=0; i<81; i++)
                {
                    v.getId(i)_____?
                }
            }
        };

        onClickListener.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);__?

Answer (score 1):

Создаём экземпляр слушателя (для примера объявляем полем класса):

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
         // получаем id нажатой кнопки
         int clicedId = v.getId();
         // делаем всё что нужно с этим id 
         // или самой кнопкой:
         // ImageButton clickedButton = (ImageButton) v;
    }
};
```

Прикрепляем наш слушатель к каждой кнопке:

```
for( int i=0; i<helth; i++) {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gold);

    for( int j=0; j<width; j++) {
        ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.question);
        imageView.setId(kid);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        mass[i][j] = kid;
        ++kid;


        tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
    }

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, i);
}
```